# aircrack-ng: how to store found key?

Tags: aircrack-ng

If I use aircrack-ng in a console, the console shows messages sometimes, ex.: new USB device plugged in when I plug in a new USB device. This messes up the screen and I cannot see that what was the key that has been found after running aircrack-ng for weeks.

**Question:** If we run aircrack-ng in the console (ALT+CTRL+F3 for example) how can we store the found key? Or redirect the system messages sent to the console to devnull?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I came through this and my suggestion is to use the `-l` option. From `man aircrack-ng`

```
-l <file> 
     Logs the key to the file specified. Overwrites the file if it already exists
```

So for example:

```
aircrack-ng -b 00:01:02:03:04:05 -l result.txt dump-01.cap
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should redirect output from aircrack-ng to file?

```
aircrack-ng -b 00:01:02:03:04:05 dump-01.cap > /path/to/file
```

If you want see output on screen and in file you should use tee

```
aircrack-ng -b 00:01:02:03:04:05 dump-01.cap | tee /path/to/file
```

Comment: since aircrack-ng shows almost every password tried... this would generate an enormously extreme big logfile, maybe this isn't the solution